# send mail in codeigniter through live server

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am trying to send email in codeignter as written in codeigniter documentation... But getting ERROR (Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.)

code---

```
 $this->load->library('email');

    $this->email->from('***@gmail.com');
    $this->email->to('***@gmail.com');

    $this->email->subject('Email Test');
    $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

    $this->email->send();

    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

Error---

```
Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
Date: Tue, 11 Sep 2018 06:47:46 +0000
From: <***@gmail.com>
Return-Path: <***@gmail.com>
Reply-To: <***@gmail.com>
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
X-Sender: ***@gmail.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <5b976512c0d0b@gmail.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
=?UTF-8?Q?Email=20Test?=
Testing the email class.
```

I Know this question might be duplicate but i didn't find any solution from any questions which were asked here...

Answer (score 4):

You have not initialized the email config setting in your code

```
$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->load->library('email');
$config = Array(
                'protocol' => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => 'tls://smtp.gmail.com',
                'smtp_port' => 587,
                'smtp_user' => '******', // your email
                'smtp_pass' => '*****', // your password
                'smtp_timeout'=>20,
                'mailtype' => 'text',
                'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
                'newline'=>"\r\n",
                'wordwrap' => TRUE
               );

 $this->email->initialize($config);
 $this->email->from('***@gmail.com');
 $this->email->to('***@gmail.com');
 $this->email->subject('Email Test');
 $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');  
 $this->email->send();
 echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

This must work for you.

Comment: The following SMTP error was encountered: 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.    ---- I GOT THIS ERROR

Comment: Change smtp_port from 465 to 587 and , add the following line of code also. $this->email->set_newline("\r\n"); or 'newline'=>"\r\n" inside $config array.

Comment: hey thank for your comments... Now it gives  this ERROR --- Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. a8-v6sm22610397oia.24 - gsmtp

Comment: Please set the following settings in your PHP.ini:
ini_set("SMTP","tls://smtp.gmail.com");
ini_set("smtp_port","587");

Comment: where can i find this PHP.ini in my server

Answer (score 0):

Please check email.php (application\config), Maybe there a problem with your configuration  Check email, like SMTP setting

You can add some config variables like the protocol. You can choose from mail, send mail or SMTP. So, obviously, I picked mail since I cannot use send mail or SMTP. You will end up with something like this:

```
$config['protocol'] = 'mail';
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a problem with your configuration. You have to set some preferences in the config file.

```
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
```

And you have to initialize the config

```
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

Comment: Unable to open a socket to Sendmail. Please check settings.
Unable to send email using PHP Sendmail. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method. -- I GOT THIS ERROR

Answer (score 0):

```
            $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';

            $config['smtp_host'] = 'mail.domain.com';

            $config['smtp_port'] = '587';

            $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';

            $config['smtp_user'] = 'info@domain.com';

            $config['smtp_pass'] = '*******';

            $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';

            $config['newline'] = "\r\n";

            $config['mailtype'] = 'html'; // or html

            $config['validation'] = TRUE; // bool whether to validate email or not      

            $this->email->initialize($config);
            $this->email->from('info@domain.com', 'Name');
            $this->email->to($emailTo);


            $this->email->subject('Reset your password');

            $body = $this->load->view('forgotmailer', $data, TRUE);

            $this->email->message($body);


            $this->email->send();
```

...................................................................

$this->load->library('email'); //add Library